# Xamarin.Forms Handling Custom Event in Custom Renderer

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a basic implementation of a custom render I will be using for handling Long Press.. It's all really based from this code http://arteksoftware.com/gesture-recognizers-with-xamarin-forms/

In my "GestureContainerView" I have an event that I called "OnHeldDown", 
[image]

How do I raise this "OnHeldDown" event if (in my Android) detected a "LongPress" ?

I tried looking up in google but couldn't find an example.

----------- UPDATE ------- (found a solution)

in PCL 
[image]

in Android 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method which checks if anyone is subscribes to the event handler and invoke it, if anyone is.

For example, create a methode like this:

```
private void RaiseOnHeldDown()
{
    if (OnHeldDown != null)
        OnHeldDown(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    // Or even do the null propagation way
    // OnHeldDown?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Of course if you'd like you can supply `EventArgs`.

Now in the event where you detect the LongPress you just call this method.

Comment: Thanks @Gerald, I just got a solution. I updated my post